# Finding operation time using awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file like below

```
RequestID=654478
Loginfo:ServerXX
Error:NA
Task=OPERATION1
File:F1
User:a
Time:3.12 ms
Network:AVL
RequestID=122644
Loginfo:ServerX2
Error:Mem
Task=OPERATION2
File:F11
User:b
Time=31.33 ms
Network:AVL
RequestID=324563
Loginfo:ServerX1
Error:Net
Task=OPERATION2
File:F1
User:c
Time=30.01 ms
Network:AVL
```

I want to find time and RequestIDs for OPERATION2

so Output should be:

```
RequestID=122644   Time=31.33 ms
RequestID=324563   Time=30.01 ms
```

I am able to find solution using combination of linux commands but  How do I do it with awk or sed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU **`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^RequestID=/{ r_id=$1 }r_id && /^Task=OPERATION2\>/{ op=$1 }
     op && /Time=/{ printf "%s\t%s\n", r_id, $0;  r_id=op="" }' file
```

- `/^Task=OPERATION2\>/` - matches line with `OPERATION2`, where `\>` is a word boundary ensures that only `OPERATION2` will be matched but not `OPERATION22`

The output:

```
RequestID=122644    Time=31.33 ms
RequestID=324563    Time=30.01 ms
```

Comment: Perfect , Thanks, What is that  "\>" for in /^Task=OPERATION2\>  It works even if I remove that , I guess you wanted to implicate end of line with \> ?

Comment: @Vicky, if you'll remove `\>` - it could match for ex. `OPERATION202` which is not desirable. See my explanation

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-only for `\>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[=:]"; OFS="\t" }
{ f[$1] = $0 }
$1 == "Network" {
    if ( f["Task"] ~ /=OPERATION2$/ ) {
        print f["RequestID"], f["Time"]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
RequestID=122644        Time=31.33 ms
RequestID=324563        Time=30.01 ms
```

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work if line `Task=OPERATION2` has trailing whitespaces

Comment: Right, nor would it work for various other inputs that don't exist just like your script won't work if there's leading white space or other inputs that also don't exist.